# Некомпетентность при наличии репутации: отклонённая правка с новыми метками

Tags: обсуждение, метки, отклонённые-правки

Хочу узнать, есть ли на этом сайте возможность какой-либо борьбы с пользователями (напр., ограничения их в правах на некоторые операции), у которых достаточно пунктов репутации, чтобы совершать модераторские действия, но недостаточно знаний в предметной области, чтобы выполнять эти действия правильно?

Описание проблемы:
я предложил [правку к вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/84113), а именно, добавил метки для более удобного поиска этой информации в будущем.
Метка luajit была добавлена потому, что вопрос касался именно этой реализации Lua (к другим реализациям Lua этот вопрос неприменим), метка ffi была добавлена потому что вопрос по сути звучал как "помогите использовать ffi (foreign function interface) в Lua для обращения к такой-то Linux API функции".

На моё предложение правки было два отзыва, оба "запретить правку".
Само по себе это не является чем-то необычным: у разных людей могут быть разные мнения по вопросу полезности правок, это, в общем-то, нормально.
Но поражает то, что из приложенных причин отказа становится ясно, что "запрещальщики" некомпетентны в вопросе, правку которого они взялись оценивать.
Откровенная бредовость причин отклонения правки также доставляет )))

Думаю, вы согласитесь, что некомпетентный пользователь с модераторской дубиной и лозунгом "мочу как хочу" вряд ли сделает сайт полезнее, а общение на нём приятнее.

Вопрос в том, есть ли технические средства противодействия такому поведению пользователей?
Первое, что приходит в голову: ограничивать множество тем, в которых человеку даётся роль модератора, напр., если пользователь имеет нулевую репутацию, заработанную на Lua-вопросах, то он не имеет права модерировать Lua-вопросы.

Comment: Правка отклонена вполне заслуженно. Ничего проблемного не вижу. Добавлять метки было не обязательно. Метки автора соответствовали его вопросу. А ваши - необязательны. Так что ваша правка излишня, что и есть в первом случае. Как вам ответили ниже - эти описания не пользователи придумали, а им надо было выбрать из списка заготовленных. Так что такие вот причины...

Comment: Сообщество обычно негативно относится к созданию новых нишевых меток. Ничего страшного в этом нет, ничьей некомпетентности - тоже. Ограничить участников в правах, которые доступны им через репутацию, просто по желанию - не получится. Обсудить подозрения на злоупотребления на Мете или в чате - всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: ваша правка могла бы быть оправдана, если бы она не требовала подтверждения от других участников (~2k репутации). Новые метки не должны создаваться с помощью механизма предложенных правок.

Answer (score 30):

Приветствую. Я один из тех, кто отклонил эту правку.

Сначала детали, касающиеся механизма предлагаемых правок вообще:

- Формулировки причин отклонения стандартны, они написаны специальным сильно обобщённым языком, из-за которого порой похоже, что проблем в сообщении больше, чем на самом деле. Краткой формулировки там нет, а она была бы полезна. Я отклонил правку с формулировкой **"Не содержит никаких улучшений"**. Об этом чуть дальше.
- Механизм предлагаемых правок предназначен для правок, которые **однозначно и безусловно улучшают** сообщения, что способен осознать любой участник. Пока не наберёте 2000 репутации, считайте, что ваши правки будут отклоняться при малейших спорных моментах.

Теперь касательно конкретного вопроса.

- Необходимость в создаваемой этой правкой метке [ffi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffi) сомнительна. Не потому что не подходит именно к этому вопросу, а потому что это слабая метка в целом. FFI (Foreign Function Interface) есть далеко не только в Lua, и сама эта метка не помогает идентифицировать технологии, о которых речь в вопросе. Вы себе представляете человека, который является экспертом по **любым FFI**? Я нет, и могу объяснить, почему: FFI служит в том числе мостом между двумя системами типов, а потому чтобы сконструировать надёжный мост, надо знать обе системы типов и, как следствие, оба языка. Поэтому гораздо полезнее разместить в вопросе метки языков, между которыми идёт интерфейс, в данном случае [lua](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) (уже есть) и [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).
- *"Метка [luajit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luajit) была добавлена потому, что вопрос касался именно этой реализации Lua (**к другим реализациям Lua этот вопрос неприменим**)"* [Не-а.](https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb) Не факт. И поскольку это не продолжение мысли автора, а **предположение**, то оно ещё и **"Явно противоречит намерениям автора"** (ещё одна причина отклонения). Поскольку выбрать несколько причин нельзя, выбирается любая из подходящих.

Заработаете 2000 репутации — ваши правки уже не будут проверяться перед публикацией. Пост-фактум её всё ещё cмогут откатить, потом, но это уже совсем другая история. Порог введён, чтобы отсечь большую часть тех, кто стремится вносить полезные правки, но пока не понимает, какие правки полезны.

Вы совершенно правильно сделали, что обратились на Мету. Лично я вполне готов ответить за свои отклонения обоснованиями.

Comment: Там есть кастомная причина "несёт вред", в которой можно указать комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy однако эта правка не несёт вред. Она просто излишняя. Вот и всё. Поэтому использовать эту причину было бы неправильно.

Comment: @intro94 этот кусочек перевода, вероятно, надо обсудить. Для единственного способа оставить особый комментарий к решению это странная пометка.

Comment: @Кнопкатык возможно и так. А возможно, что ошибка именно в переводе последнего. Обычно, в подобных опросниках, это не комментарий, а что-то вроде *"нет в списке, напишите сами"*.

Comment: Не узнал вас в гриме )

Comment: А можно ли писать собственные причины отклонения правки? Шаблонные — какой-то кошмар.

Comment: ffi метка однозначно оправдана для данного вопроса. Могут быть сомнения относительно luajit метки (наличие других реализаций ffi для lua от facebook ни о чём не говорит, например, cffi для Питона копирует тот же интерфейс). Проблема с правкой в том, что она *предлагает новые метки* и как мы убедились правильное их использование требует знания предметной области—то есть создание подобных меток не должно предлагаться в виде правок, которые могут быть подтверждены людьми  без специальных знаний.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Qwertiy об этом и написал: выбирается причина "Несёт вред", а под ней текстовое поле.

Answer (score 13):

Там не так много заготовленных вариантов, так что вполне можно отклонить и с такими.

И обращаю внимание, что речь идёт не о добавлении существующих меток, а о создании новых. Несколько странно создавать метки, применимость которых, вероятно, ограничивается одним вопросом.

Что касается компетентности, в большинстве случаев правки проверяются на адекватность и соответствие правилам, а не на техническую корректность.

Итак, создаётся метка некого продукта, который в вопросе не упоминается. И создаётся вторая метка [ffi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffi). Попробовал кинуть `ffi` в гугл - ничего хорошего не гуглится. Если уж создавать такую метку, то, вероятно, её надо назвать как-то по-другому.

Вывод: правка сомнительная и её можно отклонить.

Comment: FFI вещь как раз известная в скриптовых языках, но не Lua-специфичная. Это Foreign Function Interface.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, тем не менее, гугл на первой странице даёт единственную ссылку на английскую википедию, а остальная часть страницы забита чем-то про мошенническую компанию - не круто. Почему бы не назвать более общей меткой [tag:межъязыковое-взаимодействие]?

Comment: [tag:lua-ffi] было бы уместнее, вероятно

Comment: @Nofate, английская википедия [говорит](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), что это есть во многих языках.

Comment: Но речь-то о реализации в Lua?

Comment: Впрочем, на соседнем сайте просто ffi.

Answer (score 11):

Здравствуйте, я автор вопроса. Насчёт метки [luajit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luajit): ffi в lua присутствует и отдельной библиотекой, непосредственно вопрос к данной метке не привязан.