# Оформление сообщений

Tags: обсуждение

Какие требования/правила предъявляются при оформлении сообщений (вопросов/ответов)?

Например, касательно грамотности, стилистического оформления, стиля и особенностей написания кода, плагиата, дублирования и проч. Также степени подробности ответа.

Полагаю, это вопрос-дубликат, скиньте, пожалуйста, в комментарии ссылки на соответствующие обсуждения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очевидное: ответ должен отвечать на вопрос (непосредственно телом), вопрос должен быть по теме ([долгая история](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)). Дальнейшее исправляется редактированием, опционально с помощью наводок в комментариях. К слову о комментариях: если информации есть место в сообщении, вносите именно в него, а не в комментарий.

Об оформлении есть ряд общих "настоятельных рекомендаций":

- Как следует из названия сообщества — пишите по-русски. И не просто чтобы русскоговорящие вас поняли, а настолько грамотным русским языком, насколько можете. От того, насколько хорошо ваше сообщение поймут, непосредственно зависит польза, которую сообщение сможет принести.

  - Жаргонизмы в целом допустимы, хотя и нежелательны; их стоит снабжать определениями. [Подробности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/181100).
- [Освойте Markdown и используйте его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Бейте тексты на абзацы по смыслу (разрывами строк лучше пользоваться пореже, абзацы обычно уместнее), используйте списки где уместно, выделяйте код и цитаты соответствующим им образом.

  - Будьте прагматичны в оформлении — дайте глазам структуру, за которую можно зацепиться, но и не делайте "ежа", выделяя жирным шрифтом каждое второе слово. Если привычки пока нет, наблюдайте за тем, как сообщество приводит сообщения в более приличный вид. Большинство совершаемых правок, по моим наблюдениям, полезные.
  - Частенько [неправильно используется внутристрочное выделение для кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/181100).
- Картинок лучше избегать (когда есть выбор), но где они полезны, их рекомендуется загружать через встроенный в редактор диалог вставки изображений: так они попадут на выделенный для Stack Overflow сервис хранения картинок у Imgur. Он не считается внешним источником, т. к. связан с администрацией SO.
- Если прикладываете ссылки, не пользуйтесь сокращателями ссылок. Вообще. Заподозрят в спаме, а кому-то одного подозрения может быть достаточно для тревоги. Внезапно потерять 100 репутации ([без шуток!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)) за действие сомнительной полезности было бы очень обидно.
- Соблюдайте авторские права. Не только в сообщениях, но особенно в сообщениях. Если опираетесь на чьи-то труды, удостойте их упоминания в собственных. Большинство источников удовлетворяется атрибуцией в форме ссылки на первоисточник, но проверяйте условия конкретного источника. [Отсутствие условий = запрет на всё](https://choosealicense.com/no-license/).

Прочие вещи, которые могут делать сообщения лучше:

- Иллюстрации. Будь то картинки, ссылки на онлайн-песочницы или местные веб-сниппеты. С ними материал нагляднее.
- Дабы ответ был проверяемым, старайтесь ссылаться на канонические источники. На сайты, непосредственно связанные с создателями продуктов, о которых пишете, или на ресурсы им полностью посвящённые (вроде официальной документации или профильных сообществ). Статьи и посты в сторонних блогах тоже допустимы, но доверия им не так много.
- Русскоязычные термины. Мы [целый общественный словарь завели для этих целей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1267/181100), потихоньку наполняем. Присоединяйтесь! А то [от всех этих "имплементаций" и "фанкций" уши вянут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5694/181100). Русскоязычные термины обычно могут цепляться за уже знакомые читателю понятия просто за счёт того, что он уже знает язык, говорит на нём — и таким образом могут быть проще для понимания.

Высший пилотаж:

- Вопрос принадлежит тому, кто его написал изначально. Не меняйте сути вопроса, если только не уверены на все 100500%, что автору нужно именно это (а то [бывают приколы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6181/181100)). И осознавайте, что [можете оказаться неправы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3113/181100).
- Если вопрос плохой или в процессе закрытия, отвечать на него лучше не надо. Окей, можно, но только если вы точно знаете, на что идёте и чем это вам обернётся. Закрытие вопроса, по определению, запрет на публикацию к нему новых ответов, и просто так обычно не накладывается.
- Не бойтесь ставить под сомнение решаемую проблему, если вам кажется, что реальная проблема совсем в другом. ["Ошибка молотка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181100) нередкое явление. Задавайте вопросы, проясняйте ситуации, прежде чем бросаться писать решение или исправлять сообщение.
- [MCVE (минимальный полный воспроизводимый пример)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) чрезвычайно полезен как для вопросов, так и для ответов. Важны все компоненты: избавьтесь от лишнего контекста, но убедитесь, что всё необходимое присутствует.

Comment: Отличная выжимка получилась, браво!

Comment: Откуда сведения что Imgur принадлежит  
Stack Exchange, Inc.?

Comment: @Other это вопрос скорее к вам. Откуда такие предположения? :) Речь о выделенном аккаунте Stack Overflow у Imgur.

Comment: @Other поменял формулировку. Так понятнее?

Comment: Так о аккаунте и написали бы, а то двусмысленно вышло :) Теперь чуть лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый отвечает как может, но есть идеал, к которому надо стремиться. На мой взгляд, хороший ответ обладает следующими качествами.

- Умеренно используются средства форматирования (выделение моноширинным шрифтом, жёлтый цитатный блок и проч.)
- Написан грамотно, spell-checker не показывает предупреждений, знаки препинания поставлены в нужных местах.
- Используются канонические названия языков программирования, программ, технологий и др., в правильном регистре.
- Не содержит сленга и жаргона, а используется литературный русский язык, вся терминология - русская.
- В примерах кода используется какой-нибудь общепринятый стиль кодирования, а каждый фрагмент кода описан простыми словами.
- Если приводится какой-то законченный рабочий пример, желательно основную часть вынести отдельно. (Особенно это актуально для ответов про HTML/CSS/JavaScript).
- Есть ссылка для дальнейшего изучения проблемы, например, в документацию или в какой-нибудь блог, где рассматривается затронутая тема.

В принципе, обычно бывает достаточно небольшого блока кода* + абзаца пояснений, либо просто двух-трёх абзацев нормального текста. Степень детальности ответа на самом деле зависит от уровня спрашивающего (если вопрос свежий) или от вашего желания.

Стоит заметить, что на существование ответа на Stack Overflow никак не влияют другие сайты. Однако при копировании текстов из других источников следует соблюдать лицензии - она должна разрешать копирование с указанием ссылки на источник. Впрочем, я уверен, иногда даже банальная копипаста может быть полезна, особенно, если внизу написать, откуда она взялась.

<sub>* до 15 строк, вместо кода бывает полезна картинка</sub>

---

К вопросам, скорее всего, применимы все те же критерии за исключением примеров кода (они не обязательны) и, разумеется, ссылок для дальнейшего изучения. Типичная длина вопроса - от одного предложения до двух-трёх абзацев.

При составлении вопроса особое внимание надо уделить заголовку - он должен отражать всю суть, а не быть набором каких-то ключевых слов. Часто бывает так, что лучше вначале написать текст вопроса, а уж потом придумать к нему заголовок. (Как на сочинении по русскому языку).